# How to charge amount less than the authorization amount in Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments, capture

I am trying the following and getting error:
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php on line 156

Here is my code where I am first authorization $25.00 with capture as false. Then want to capture with a lesser amount of $23.00. The sample is not very clear.

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 2500,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "capture" => false,
  "customer" => $stripecustid));

$chargeid = $charge->id;

$ch = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($chargeid);

$captured = $ch->capture(2300);
```

Comment: i see no `foreach()`

Comment: @Dagon It's in the API. Which means that one of the parameters should be an array, but it isn't.

Comment: Which API call is the error happening during?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
$captured = $ch->capture(array(
    "amount" => 2300
));
```

Here is the documentation for the "capture charge" API call: https://stripe.com/docs/api#capture_charge

Comment: @ Ywain. Thanks got it.